# using frame like div

Tags: html, frame

When I use `frame` tag like this,

```
<frameset rows="425,*" noresize frameborder=0>
    <frame name="top" src="./top.html" scrolling="no">
    <frame name="bottom" src="./bottom.html">
</frameset>
```

if I scroll, then *top.html* stays at the top and just *bottom.html* gets scrolled.

I want to implement the scroll to *top.html* as well just like I would scroll any other `div`.

Is it possible? I must use `frame` tag because there is a music player at top so need to preserve that. ,even page change. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not going to make this an answer because it's likely not what you want to hear, but you _really_ should consider not using framesets. They're rarely used now and present unexpected behaviour, particularly on mobile devices (which is going to account for approaching half of users). Using `{position: fixed}` in CSS can create the same page effect far easier, and AJAX page loading can deal with the navigation problem. If you'd like code suggestions for that in an answer I can provide them.

Comment: thanks to answer! I use audio tag in top. And I want maintain this music player even I change the page. If I use audio tag in div at one file all, then when I change the page, the music will be stopped.. and will be restarted maybe. I don't want that.

Comment: Understood, so if you load subsequent pages using AJAX within a central frame this will have the same effect. The easiest way to do this is using `jQuery` and the `.load()` method, which allows the contents of a page to be quickly loaded into a container element. http://api.jquery.com/load/